# A homeomorphism between two CW complexes is a cellular map

Tags: general-topology, cw-complexes

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two CW complexes. Is it true that any homeomorphism $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ is a cellular map, meaning that $f(X^n)\subset Y^n$ ? where $X^n$ refers to the $n-$skeleton of $X$.

Comment: No, take a polygonal circle and rotate it a bit. The vertices don't map to vertices.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Why not an official answer?

Answer (score 1):

No. The interval $[0,1]$ can be given CW-structures $X$ such such that $X^0 =\{ \{0\},\{1\}\}$ and $Y$ such that $Y^0 = \{\{0\},\{1/2\},\{1\}\}$. Then $id : Y \to X$ is not cellular.